# Using Visual Studio Cordova integration CTP with WinJs

Tags: cordova, winjs, sample, visual-studio-cordova

Did anyone used the newly launched Visual Studio Cordova integration CTP (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstud...) and created a WinJs application . The Sample WinJs application they have is written in Type Script (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WinJS-TODO-Sample-for-17295485). I want an example in JavaScript.

Actually I want the WinJs file to Use in My Application. Event from the GitHub Page I am getting the Development source where as I need the Production minifieed Versions so that I can Directly use them In my application.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try and answer this in 2 parts:

### Sample Apps

Sample applications - we've created and published 3 Todo apps in total, 2 of them in JavaScript and 1 in TypeScript:

- AngularJS [JavaScript template] ([link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398516))
- BackboneJS [JavaScript template] ([link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398517))
- WinJS [TypeScript template] ([link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398518))

On getting a JavaScript based WinJS project – The TypeScript code actually generates JavaScript files.  You can largely just build the app with TypeScript and then swap out the .ts files for the .js files to convert it to a pure JS project.

### WinJS

WinJS can be downloaded and built using Grunt. Alternately, you can find pre-compiled versions of the framework here:

- http://try.buildwinjs.com/lib/winjs/js/base.min.js?v1.0.86
- http://try.buildwinjs.com/lib/winjs/js/ui.min.js?v1.0.86

Comment: I tried to execute the sample also but didn't got the js files in output. Will is be possible for you guys to share the code in Js format only

Comment: Output of TypeScript is JavaScript, so look into your project location, you will also find the corresponding JavaScript for any TypeScript file